# Non-empty resolvent set, then operator closed?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, sp.spectral-theory, operator-theory

On Hilbert spaces, the following is true:

Let $T$ be a densely-defined linear operator with non-empty resolvent set, then $T$ is closed.

The obvious proof I see to show this uses explicitly the Hilbert space structure which is why I would like to ask:

Is the same result true for operators on Banach spaces?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I would consider the obvious proof uses only the Banach space structure.

If $\lambda$ is in the resolvent set, the graph $G(T)$ of $T$ maps in an obvious way to the graph of $(T-\lambda I)^{-1}$:
$G(T) = f^{-1}(G((T-\lambda I)^{-1}))$ where 
$$f:\;(x, y) \mapsto (y-\lambda x, x)$$
Since $f$ is continuous from $X \times X$ to itself and $G((T-\lambda I)^{-1})$ is closed, $G(T)$ is closed.

Answer (score 4):

(This is really a very long comment...)

I think maybe the actual question comes about because some of the terminology in this area is hazy.  Let $T:X\supseteq D(T)\rightarrow X$ be a linear operator on a Banach space $X$.  For example, [Resolvent set, wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolvent_set) *defines* $\lambda\in\mathbb C$ to be in the resolvent if:

1. $T-\lambda I$ injects;
2. $(T-\lambda I)^{-1}$ is bounded; and
3. $(T-\lambda I)^{-1}$ is densely defined

Under this definition, it is *not* true that having non-empty resolvent set implies closed.  For example, let $X=\ell^2$, let $D(T) = c_{00}$ be the space of eventually 0 sequences, and define $T((x_n)) = (nx_n)$.  Set $\lambda=0$ and check the conditions: $T$ is bijective between $c_{00}$ and $c_{00}$; $T^{-1}((x_n)) = (n^{-1}x_n)$ is bounded; $c_{00}$ is dense in $\ell^2$.  But $T$ is not closed; only *closable*.

Let's be a bit more precise.  For any $T:X\supseteq D(T)\rightarrow X$, if $T$ is injective then we may *define* $T^{-1}:D(T^{-1})\rightarrow X$ by setting $D(T^{-1})$ to be the image of $T$, and defining $T^{-1}(T(x)) = x$ for $x\in D(T)$.  This is well-defined as $T$ is injective.  Let's compare the graphs:
$$ \mathcal{G}(T) = \{ (x,T(x)) : x \in D(T) \}, \quad
\mathcal{G}(T^{-1}) = \{ (T(x),x) : x\in D(T) \}, $$
so clearly $T$ is closed if and only if $T^{-1}$ is.  As Robert Israel observes, it is also true that $T$ is closed if and only if $T-\lambda I$ is closed, and hence $(T-\lambda I)^{-1}$ *closed* does imply that $T$ is closed.

There are further definitions of "resolvent set".  E.g. [Engel, Nagel](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=U3k8yfchaPYC&lpg=PR7&ots=8ZDD91cTR7&dq=One-Parameter%20Semigroups%20for%20Linear%20Evolution%20Equations&lr&pg=PA239#v=snippet&q=resolvent%20set&f=false) *define* $\lambda$ to be in the resolvent set if $T-\lambda I:D(T)\rightarrow X$ is *bijective*, that is, $T-\lambda I$ has range the whole of $X$.  They also by definition already assume $T$ is closed, so that then $(T-\lambda I)^{-1}$ is closed and hence by the Closed Graph Theorem, bounded.

Answer (score 4):

STANDING ASSUMPTIONS: Let $T:D_T\rightarrow X$ be a linear operator, where $X$ is a normed space (or metrizable TVS) and $D_T\subset X$.

DEFINITION: Then $\lambda$ belongs to the *resolvent set* $\rho(T)$ iff $T-\lambda I$ is one-to-one and **onto** and its inverse is bounded.

LEMMA. **A linear operator $T$ in a normed space $X$ is closed if$^\dagger$ it has a non-empty resolvent set.**

PROOF. Let $D_T\owns x_n\rightarrow x$, $Tx_n\rightarrow y$.$^\ddagger$ Let $\lambda$ be in the resolvent set. Then $x=\lim_n x_n = \lim_n (T-\lambda)^{-1}(T-\lambda)x_n=(T-\lambda)^{-1}(y-\lambda x)$ (+).
Therefore, $x\in (T-\lambda)^{-1}(X)=D_T$.
By (+), $(T-\lambda)x=(T-\lambda)(T-\lambda)^{-1}(y-\lambda x)=(y-\lambda x)$;
 hence $Tx=y$, so $T$ is closed, QED.

Note: Robert Israel's shorter proof on this page shows the same for any TVS (if you require that the inverse is a continuous operator). The above proof (that works for all metrizable TVSs) might be easier for some readers.

---

$\dagger$) The "if" in the lemma cannot be reversed, as some closed operators (even on $\ell^2$) have an empty resolvent set, by https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3262168/closed-operator-with-trivial-resolvent-set

$\ddagger$) In a metrizable space, a set is closed iff it is sequentially closed. So the graph $G_T:=\{(x,Tx):\, x\in D_T\}$ is closed iff $G_T\owns (x_n,Tx_n)\rightarrow (x,y)\ \Rightarrow\ (x,y)\in G_T$ (i.e., $x\in D_T$ and $y=Tx$).

Note that your assumption that the operator is densely defined was not needed. This is a strict improvement:

EXAMPLE. Let $L$ denote the inverse of the right-shift $R:(x_1,x_2,\cdots)\rightarrow (0,x_1,x_2,\cdots)$. Then dom$L=R(\ell^2)$ is not dense, as $(1,0,0,\cdots)$ is not in its closure, but yet the (onto-)resolvent set $\rho(L)$ is nonempty, as $(L-0)^{-1}=R$ and hence $0\in\rho(L)$.

---

This "onto" definition seems to be standard:
Rudin: F.A., 13.26 &
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_(functional_analysis)#Spectrum_of_an_unbounded_operator

**Your claim is true only for this standard definition ("onto"), not for the older definition ("dense range" in place of "onto")**, by Matthew Daws' example. For closed operators, the two definitions are equivalent. For a further discussion on this and the two definitions, see: [Standard definition of a resolvent: A-zI must be onto, not merely have a dense range?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/348543/standard-definition-of-a-resolvent-a-zi-must-be-onto-not-merely-have-a-dense-r)