# Standard definition of a resolvent: A-zI must be onto, not merely have a dense range?

Tags: sp.spectral-theory

STANDING ASSUMPTIONS: Let $T:D_T\rightarrow X$ be a linear operator, where $X$ is a normed space and $D_T\subset X$.

DEFINITION 1 ("onto"): A complex number $\lambda$ belongs to the *resolvent set* $\rho(T)$ iff $T-\lambda I$ is one-to-one and **onto** and its inverse is bounded.

---

DEFINITION 2 ("dense range"):  A complex number$\lambda$ belongs to the *dresolvent set* $\rho(T)$ iff $T-\lambda I$ is one-to-one and has a **dense range** and its inverse is bounded.

So the only difference is that one requires a **dense range** instead of "onto".

**I believe that the onto-definition is now the standard one and the dense-definition now rare** (when not equivalent).

**QUESTION: Is this really the case?**

To me it seems that, in current papers, usually the resolvent is not defined, but when you dig deeply in the references, you find that the onto-definition is used. (But I have now checked this just for 2 papers.) This is dangerous, as old classics may use the dense-definition. Often there is no difference:

LEMMA: **For closed operators** (hence for **bounded** operators) the two definitions are **equivalent**.

PROOF: Set $A:=T-\lambda I$. Let $R=A^{-1}$.Given any $y\in X$, density implies $y=\lim Ax_n$ for some $\{x_n\}\subset$Dom$\,T$. But $\lim x_n=\lim RA x_n=R\lim A x_n=Ry$, hence $(Ry,y)\in$graph$(A)$, as $A$ is closed, QED.

FACT: The definitions are not equivalent.

PROOF: any of Example 1, Example 2 and Example 3 below. QED.

EXAMPLE 1. Let $T$ be the identity operator $I$ restricted to a proper dense subset of $X$. (This is possible even for $X=\ell^2$.) Then $I=(T-0)^{-1}$, hence $T$ has the dresolvent $I$ at $0$ but not a resolvent, QED.

EXAMPLE 2: Let $X=\ell^2$. Define $h\in\ell^2$ by $h_i=2^{1-i}$.
Define $R\in\mathcal L(X)$ by $Rg=g-g_1 h$. Then $Rg=0$ iff $g\in {\mathbb C} h$.
Set $Y:=c_c$ (sequences that are zero outside a finite set).
Then $R$ is 1-1 on $Y$. Set $D_A:=RY$, $A:=R^{-1}$ to define a 
 linear operator $A$ whose **dresolvent at $0$** is $(A-0I)^{-1}=R$ (as range$(A)=Y$ is dense, $A$ is 1-1 and $R$ is bounded) but which has **no resolvent** (proof: not onto)
 and is **not closable**
 (proof: if $Y\owns y_n\rightarrow h$, then $x_n:=Ry_n\rightarrow Rh=0$
 but $Ax_n=y_n\rightarrow h\ne0$, QED).

EXAMPLE 3: Here 
$$T:\mathcal{D}(T)\subseteq X\to Y:\text{ injective, dense range, continuously invertible, not closable!}$$
Therefore, $0$ lies in its spectrum but not in its dspectrum. Details:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/819526/operator-not-closable

(BTW, the $T$ of Example 1 is closable and its closure $I$ does have a resolvent at $0$. The $A$ of Example 2 is not densely defined, so Example 3 is better in that sense.)

The difference is often important:

LEMMA. A linear operator $T$ in a normed space $X$ is closed if it has a non-empty resolvent set. However, the reverse is not true, and a non-closed operator may have a non-empty dresolvent set.

PROOF: [Non-empty resolvent set, then operator closed?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/264740/non-empty-resolvent-set-then-operator-closed/)

The difference between the two definitions is discussed here:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/815377/resolvent-definition
But my question is the above, i.e., is the dresolvent definition fairly obsolete and does the spectrum nowadays usually mean the onto-spectrum?

N.B. Many books define (unbounded) linear operators **invertible** when they are 1-1 and onto and have a bounded inverse (but some other books, e.g., Goldberg, define an inverse for any 1-1 operator). At least in many of them, $0\in\rho(T)$ is defined analogously, leading to the onto-resolvent definition.

N.B. C-Star-W-Star calls the onto-definition "usual" here after another commenter (D.F.) suggested the opposite: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1345613/definition-of-resolvent-set#comment2737222_1345626

*Non-normed spaces*: Instead of "bounded" one should write "the restriction of a continuous operator that is defined on the whole $X$" to generalize this to all TVSs. For normed spaces this makes no difference to either definition (and the non-equivalence remains).

"ONTO"-DEFINITION IS USED IN:

- Rudin: Functional Analysis, 13.26
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_(functional_analysis)#Spectrum_of_an_unbounded_operator & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decomposition_of_spectrum_(functional_analysis) (proof: *continuous spectrum* consists of non-eigenvalues for which the range of T-z is dense but not onto).
- Alessandra Lunardi: Analytic Semigroups and Optimal Regularity in Parabolic Problems, 1995.
  (Proof: p. 33 (below Def. 2.0.1) says that nonempty resolvent implies closedness.)
- Pazy: Semigroups of ..., 1983. (Proof: Requires $z-A$ boundedly "invertible", which must mean the onto-definition, as the alternative would be that not even denseness was required, merely 1-1.)

"DENSE"-DEFINITION IS USED IN:

- Goldberg: Unbounded Linear Operators (1966), Definition II.5.2, p. 71.
- Hille-Phillips ("Revised Edition", p. 54, Def. 2.16.1)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolvent_set

Comment: A couple of trivial comments that seems to be related. 1) $\mathbb{Q}$ is not a Banach space. 2) doesn't usually one require a function to be surjective in order to define its inverse?

Comment: 1) Thank you; I replaced it by 2 correct examples. 2) I think so ("usually") but I'm not certain, and at least Goldberg only requires 1-1 (and defines the bounded inverse on on the range only; though it then has a unique bounded extension to whole $X$). I think that if one defines the resolvent by "$z-T$ has a bounded inverse" [Pazy], then they surely use the "onto"-definition. If one writes "$z-T$ is 1-1 and has a dense range and a bounded inverse" [Goldberg], then it is the dense-definition.